# How to animate an object with <img> tag move along a path?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

I want to create an animation in which an object (in this case, the first blue line in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDwQ2.png) move along an svg path. The line is provided in the form of PNG.

I tried using the  tag but it's not changing anything.

Here is basically an example of what I wanted [animate image on SVG Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215939/animate-image-on-svg-path).

Below is my code.

```
          <svg height="238.158mm" viewbox="0 0 1920 900" width="508.071mm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
            <path class="green-line" d="M 1.09,741.82
                                        C 1.09,741.82 17.09,734.00 17.09,734.00
                                        17.09,734.00 51.45,718.73 51.45,718.73
                                        51.45,718.73 74.55,709.09 74.55,709.09
                                        74.55,709.09 110.91,694.73 110.91,694.73
                                        110.91,694.73 157.45,678.18 157.45,678.18
                                        157.45,678.18 199.82,665.27 199.82,665.27
                                        199.82,665.27 253.82,650.55 253.82,650.55
                                        253.82,650.55 312.67,638.00 312.67,638.00
                                        312.67,638.00 387.67,627.33 387.67,627.33
                                        387.67,627.33 453.33,621.00 453.33,621.00
                                        453.33,621.00 505.33,618.67 505.33,618.67
                                        505.33,618.67 576.67,620.33 576.67,620.33
                                        576.67,620.33 619.33,623.67 619.33,623.67
                                        619.33,623.67 636.67,625.00 636.67,625.00
                                        636.67,625.00 715.67,636.33 716.00,636.33
                                        716.33,636.33 783.00,648.33 783.00,648.33
                                        783.00,648.33 846.67,665.00 846.67,665.00
                                        846.67,665.00 895.33,679.00 895.33,679.00
                                        895.33,679.00 951.33,697.67 951.33,697.67
                                        951.33,697.67 1026.00,723.33 1026.00,723.33
                                        1026.00,723.33 1097.33,747.67 1097.33,747.67
                                        1097.33,747.67 1176.67,776.00 1176.67,776.00
                                        1176.67,776.00 1236.67,798.00 1236.67,798.00
                                        1236.67,798.00 1265.00,807.67 1265.00,807.67
                                        1265.00,807.67 1316.00,826.55 1316.00,826.55
                                        1316.00,826.55 1351.64,837.27 1351.64,837.27
                                        1351.64,837.27 1389.09,847.82 1389.09,847.82
                                        1389.09,847.82 1429.45,858.36 1429.45,858.36
                                        1429.45,858.36 1452.91,863.82 1452.91,863.82
                                        1452.91,863.82 1470.81,868.06 1470.81,868.06
                                        1470.81,868.06 1489.88,872.06 1489.88,872.06
                                        1489.88,872.06 1503.88,874.25 1503.88,874.25
                                        1503.88,874.25 1513.50,875.94 1513.50,875.94
                                        1513.50,875.94 1533.44,879.31 1533.44,879.31
                                        1533.44,879.31 1546.38,881.56 1546.38,881.56
                                        1546.38,881.56 1556.19,883.00 1556.19,883.00
                                        1556.19,883.00 1566.19,884.19 1566.19,884.19
                                        1566.19,884.19 1596.69,887.69 1596.69,887.69
                                        1596.69,887.69 1614.12,889.88 1614.12,889.88
                                        1614.12,889.88 1633.06,891.12 1633.06,891.12
                                        1633.06,891.12 1645.25,892.25 1645.25,892.25
                                        1645.25,892.25 1682.62,895.06 1682.62,895.06
                                        1682.62,895.06 1693.31,896.12 1693.31,896.12
                                        1693.31,896.12 1707.22,897.04 1707.22,897.04
                                        1707.22,897.04 1723.17,897.78 1723.17,897.78
                                        1723.17,897.78 1729.09,898.22 1729.09,898.22
                                        1729.09,898.22 1763.43,899.22 1763.43,899.22
                                        1763.43,899.22 1768.74,899.48 1768.78,899.48
                                        1768.83,899.48 1774.59,899.56 1774.59,899.56
                                        1774.59,899.56 1778.34,899.88 1778.34,899.88
                                        1778.34,899.88 1779.50,899.97 1779.50,899.97
                                        1779.50,899.97 1793.39,899.91 1793.39,899.91
                                        1793.39,899.91 1807.48,899.96 1807.48,899.96
                                        1807.48,899.96 1817.13,900.00 1817.13,900.00
                                        1817.13,900.00 1822.35,899.83 1822.43,899.87
                                        1822.52,899.91 1884.73,899.91 1884.73,899.91
                                        1884.73,899.91 1897.73,899.91 1897.73,899.91
                                        1897.73,899.91 1918.64,900.27 1918.64,900.27
                                        1918.64,900.27 1919.62,900.00 1919.62,900.00" id="animatePath" style="fill:none;stroke:none ;stroke-miterlimit:10;"> 
            </path> 
            <image height="250px" id="car" width="1918px" x="0" xlink:href="/data/cms/images/1668585137_img-top-panel-curve.png" y="500"> 
              <animatemotion begin="0s" dur="20s" repeatcount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" xlink:href="#car"> 
                <mpath xlink:href="#animatePath"> 
                </mpath> 
              </animatemotion> 
            </image> 
          </svg>
        </div>
```

Comment: do you want to move object along with svg path, give some more detail or example

Comment: @Mayur I want to animate an image so that it will move along an svg path.

Comment: do you want like satellite moving round with earth like that , need some more clarity, or add good image of required output.

Comment: @Mayur I updated my question for clarity. Thank you so much

Comment: Are you sure you want to animate the wavy line image and not the "car"?  [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/gOKGEzW)